# How to use struct.unpack to extract int from list of bytes in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Assuming, I have a list bites with constant length

```
>>> chunk = [b'\xd0', b'\x00', b'\xd5', b'\x00', b'\xdf', b'\x00', b'\xaa', b'U']
>>> print(type(chunk))
<class 'list'>
>>> print(chunk)
[b'\xd0', b'\x00', b'\xd5', b'\x00', b'\xdf', b'\x00', b'\xaa', b'U']
```

And I want to get a single int from it, which could be done this way:

```
>>> a = int.from_bytes(chunk[2], byteorder='little')
>>> b = int.from_bytes(chunk[3], byteorder='little')
>>> decoded = a * 256 + b
>>> print(decoded)
213
```

How do I use `struct.unpack` for that purpose?
Several ways I failed:

```
>>> print(struct.unpack('<xxHxxxx', chunk))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'
```

```
>>> tmp = bytes(chunk)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

```
>>> tmp = bytes([chunk])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

```
>>> tmp = bytearray(chunk)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

The initial motivation was to check if `struct.unpack` is any faster then already working code. But now I want to figure out the right way to use it.

Oh, and if there is any more efficient way, I would be glad to know that too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in how you convert a `list` of bytes to `bytes`. You can do this with `b''.join(list)` and then apply your struct unpack.

Example:

```
>>> import struct
# your list of bytes
>>> lst = [b'\xd0', b'\x00', b'\xd5', b'\x00', b'\xdf', b'\x00', b'\xaa', b'U']

# Convert into `bytes`
>>> bts = b''.join(lst)

# Unpack
>>> print(struct.unpack('<xxHxxxx', bts))
(213,)
```

Note that you can also unpack the returned tuple with:

```
>>> (a,) = struct.unpack('<xxHxxxx', bts)
>>> a
213
```